# Fragment not attached to a context

Tags: android, android-fragment, kotlin, context, android-handler

При пересоздании активности редко получаю ошибку связаную с фрагментом (фрагменты вложеные в фрагмент). На сколько я понял с логов следует что ошибка возникает из-за того что активити-хост не доступна в данный момент:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fragment TemperatureFragment{aeecb3d} not attached to a context.
```

Проверка на доступность активити-хоста `isAdded` не дала ожидаемого результата, видимо я не совсем понял природу данной ошибки. В самом фрагменте запускаю хендлер и уничтожаю `Handler`.

```
class TemperatureFragment : BaseFragment(), LooperParameter.DataReadyCallback {
override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater,
                              container: ViewGroup?,
                              savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
 ...
    if (isAdded){
       looperParameter = LooperParameter(this)
       looperParameter.startLooper()
       Log.i(TAG, "Temperature looper is started...")
       }
  ...
  }
}

override fun dataReady() {
... //ошибка возникает здесь
}

override fun onPause() {
    super.onPause()
    looperParameter.stopLooper()
    Log.i(TAG, "Temperature looper is destroyed...")
```

Код `LooperParameter:`

```
class LooperParameter(fragment : DataReadyCallback) : Runnable {
    companion object {
        const val TAG: String = "LooperParameter"
        const val DELAY_RESPONSE: Long = 200
    }

    private val handler : Handler = Handler()
    private val dataReadyCallback : DataReadyCallback = fragment

    fun startLooper(){
        handler.post(this)
    }

    fun stopLooper(){
        handler.removeCallbacks(this)
    }

    override fun run() {
        dataReadyCallback.dataReady()
        handler.postDelayed(this, DELAY_RESPONSE)
        Log.i(TAG, "New data called...")
    }

    interface DataReadyCallback {
        fun dataReady()
    }
}
}
```

Кода много поэтому указал лишь критические части кода.

Answer (score 0):

Представьте, что ваш фрагмент уже отсоединили от активити, а `DELAY_RESPONSE` еще не прошел.

```
handler.postDelayed(this, DELAY_RESPONSE)
```

Вот тогда и случится то, что вы описываете.

Правильным подходом будет ловить `onAttach()` и `onDetach()` чтобы точно знать, когда есть контекст активити, когда нет.

Comment: Не совсем понял предложеное вами решение..

Comment: Возможно, это я не совсем понял ваше решение. Скорее всего у вас `onPause` не отрабатывает как надо. Я бы советовал перенести код в `onDetach` а инициализацию проводить в `onAttach`.

Comment: согласен, в любом другом случае так бы и сделал, но метод DataReady в таком случае может быть вызван еще до вызова onCreateView что будет вызывать эту же ошибку почти всегда.

Comment: Добавьте в имплементацию  `dataReady()` нужные проверки. Looper не должен заботится, когда можно а когда нельзя вызывать callback.